# How to get data of specific documents from firebase realtime database?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image - first column its button with value which i need to paste in parametre](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udf0h.png) .
I try to get the rest of the information about the document from the database when I click on the button! but in the console I get the whole list of documents! I need to send the id of the document from the first column of the table to "equalTo () '" to get the data of a specific document

```
firebase.database().ref("recommendations")
.orderByChild("ID")
.equalTo()
.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Comment: I have never worked with firebase, but don't you need to add some parameter to the `equalTo` method, to filter by your specific ID?

Comment: yes, but i dont know how to sent id to this parameter from html

Comment: From HTML? Is it in some input box? Then you have to use Javascript or JQuery to get the value of that field and add it to your `where` clause.

Comment: I updated the question.
in the table I have a list from the database and the first column is a button with a value that must be sent to the equalTo () parameter...

Comment: It sounds like you're building an HTML table out of the data in the database, and want the user to be able to interact with each row. You will need to detect what row they click on, and then extract the value from the first column. This has nothing to do with Firebase, so if you need help there, I recommend writing the question without using Firebase as it makes it much more likely that somebody with the right knowledge will help. See [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).